# how to delete catalog price rule after order placed ?

Tags: orders, event-observer, catalog, catalog-price-rules, delete

i want to delete catalog price rule after order placed

how to delete catalog price rule after order placed help of event observer Method

Comment: Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($rulesId)

Comment: Are you sure, you want to delete a **catalog** price rule as soon as it has been used once and not a **shopping cart** price rule? Catalog price rules are the rules which are visible in the catalog as special prices and recalculated each night. If you can elaborate what you need this for, you might get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaibhav,You can use `checkout_submit_all_after` event.This event is occur after order place.

**Step1**:You need load catalog rules by Id and then  remove

```
  $model = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
        $model->load($rulesId) );
        $model->delete();
```

**Step2:** remove  catalog rules.

```
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/flag')->loadSelf()
            ->setState(1)
            ->save();
```

**Edit: delete by name**

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')
        ->getResourceCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFiler('name',$rulesName);
    $collection->addWebsitesToResult();

foreach($collection as $each){
$model = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
$model->load($each) )->getId(;
$model->delete();

}
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/flag')->loadSelf()
        ->setState(1)
        ->save();
```

Comment: at which event ?

Comment: and what to do if we want to delete by name of rule

Comment: yes.you  can do this

Comment: i need to change price of product at cart .
on product page it's displayed original price but after click on add to cart it's display custom price on cart page with help of event observer 

u have any idea how to do this

Comment: I want to delete catalog price rule in magento 2